# How to schedule a task using python

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I am working on python script which schedules a task. I have created a GUI from where user schedules his task.The GUI is as shown below

[image]
   Now my script has to receive the inputs from this GUI and schedule the task.I know the    command line parameters:

taskname--> /TN
   startdate--> /SD
   starttime--> /ST
   select the day of the week--> /D

My question is, what is the command line parameters for 'Recur every day' and 'Recur every week' to schedule a task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a python script to schedule a task,

FOR ONE TIME

```
 cmd='SCHTASKS /Create /SC "%s" /TN "%s" /TR "%s" /SD "%s" /ST "%s"'%("ONCE","calc","C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe","10/07/2013","11.47")
 proc=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

DAILY FOR EVERY 2 DAYS

```
 cmd='SCHTASKS /Create /SC "%s" /MO "%s" /TN "%s" /TR "%s" /SD "%s" /ST "%s"'%("DAILY","2","calc","C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe","10/07/2013","11.47")
 proc=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

EVERY MONDAY FOR EVERY 2 WEEKS

```
 cmd='SCHTASKS /Create /SC "%s" /MO "%s" /D "%s" /TN "%s" /TR "%s" /SD "%s" /ST "%s"'%("DAILY","2","MON","calc","C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe","10/07/2013","11.47")
 proc=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It appears to me to be something like: /SC DAILY or /SC WEEKLY